# Chrome 26 "Inspect Element" copy-paste issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, inspect

For some reason, i'm not able to paste css code to the "inspect element" window..

Lets say I want to test "font-weight:bold; color: red" and paste it to the element.style, which results with:
[image]

As you can see, only the "font-weight" was pasted.

This is really annoying as I was used to just paste the code as is...
Especially if i'm trying a couple of styles from a tutorial or a solution to a problem I found here.

Is it only me? Anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Nevermind. It looks like I was still on Chrome 25. The fact that it worked on 25 and now it doesn't sounds like a bug to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is known and will be fixed in the next release :

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/RC3i6GW2h28

Comment: Thanks :) I actually opened a bug to them too and they closed it as "fixed". I hope it will be ok in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

You could always edit the style in-line for testing:

Right click tag.  Click 'add attribute'.  Type `style="` ctrl+ v `"`

Not sure if there's a more elegant solution.  `element.style` just adds a `style=""` attribute anyway.

Comment: I know I can, but it's just not as conformable and fast as just "copy-pasting"... Thank you anyway.